# If/Else problem in SQL to get valid value

Tags: sql, if-statement, azure-databricks

I want to get a VBELN field from VBFA table.
But to get the valid value, I need to follow this logic:

```
Get VBFA where FPLTR = ZTB_Driver-FPLTR AND FPLNR = ZTB_Driver-FPLNR

SUM VBFA-RFWRT
IF VBFA-RFWRT = 0 THEN VBELN = space
ELSE VBELN = VBFA-VBELN
```

In order to get the valid VBELN value, I need to get rows from VBFA table where the FPLNR and FPLTR field has the same value with FPLNT and FPLTR in ZTB_DRIVER table.
VBLEN may have duplicated rows, so I need to SUM the RFWRT field.
If the result is 0, then the VBELN would be space/empty.
If the result is not 0, then the VBELN value is just the same as what it's presented in VBFA-VBELN.

For this logic:

```
Get VBFA where FPLTR = ZTB_Driver-FPLTR AND FPLNR = ZTB_Driver-FPLNR
```

I've done this:

```
SELECT * FROM VBFA a
JOIN ZTB_Driver b ON a.FPLTR = b.FPLTR AND a.FPLNR = b.FPLNR
```

But, I have difficulity with this logic:

```
SUM VBFA-RFWRT
IF VBFA-RFWRT = 0 THEN VBELN = space
ELSE VBELN = VBFA-VBELN
```

I attached sample input dan expected output here
[sample](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1oLC_B2QiK-iGbKk2sJ8869twQLO20RXmgjCHUvtHriM/edit?usp=sharing)

What would you do to convert this logic in SQL query?
I'd really appreciate any inputs.
Thank you!

SOLVED!

```
SELECT c.VBELN,
   CASE WHEN SUM(RFWRT) = 0 THEN ' '
   ELSE VBELN
   END AS VBELN_2
   FROM (
         SELECT a.* FROM VBFA a
         JOIN ZTB_Driver b ON a.FPLTR = b.FPLTR AND a.FPLNR = b.FPLNR) c
GROUP BY c.VBELN
```

Comment: can you provide your sample input and expected output?

Comment: Hey @RakeshGovindula, thank you for checking out my question. I already attached the sample of my data. Thank you.

Comment: what is ZTB_Driver here, what are the values for it. and you have added your sample input data, add your expected output also.

Comment: @RakeshGovindula ZTB_Driver is another table for a refrence to get VBELN in VBFA table. ZTB_Driver and VBFA table both have VBELN, FPLNR, and FPLTR. If both table has similar FPLNR and FPLTR value, then we'll get the similar VBELN value from both table, but we'll only fetch the VBELN from VBFA table. The expected output is in the same file, different sheet.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because stated as solved (in question)